# Visual C++ compiler internal error for including pretty_print.h

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I have got a new SSD, so I re-installed my OS, along with Visual Studio. Now,  I am getting a pretty weird bug with Visual C++ 15.9 (and Visual Studio 2017?).

If I try including pretty print in main.cpp, these lines appear:

```
>------ Build started: Project: Test, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Test.cpp
1>c:\users\nguyen thanh\source\repos\test\test\pretty_print.h(64): fatal error C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler.
1>(compiler file 'd:\agent\_work\2\s\src\vctools\compiler\cxxfe\sl\p1\c\types.c', line 4563)
1> To work around this problem, try simplifying or changing the program near the locations listed above.
1>Please choose the Technical Support command on the Visual C++
1> Help menu, or open the Technical Support help file for more information
1>c:\users\nguyen thanh\source\repos\test\test\pretty_print.h(71): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'pretty_print::detail::has_begin_end<T>' being compiled
1>Done building project "Test.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Here are the lines that have problem

```
template <typename T>
struct has_begin_end : private sfinae_base
{
private:
    template <typename C>
    static yes & f(typename std::enable_if<
        std::is_same<decltype(static_cast<typename C::const_iterator(C::*)() const>(&C::begin)),
        typename C::const_iterator(C::*)() const>::value>::type *);

    template <typename C> static no & f(...);

    template <typename C>
    static yes & g(typename std::enable_if<
        std::is_same<decltype(static_cast<typename C::const_iterator(C::*)() const>(&C::end)),
        typename C::const_iterator(C::*)() const>::value, void>::type*);

    template <typename C> static no & g(...);
}
```

You can see the full source of pretty_print.h here: https://github.com/louisdx/cxx-prettyprint

Does anyone have a clue what should I do? I tried tinkering around with preprocessor flags and optimization flags, but they do not seem like the problem.

Edit: everything goes back to normal if I uninstall the latest version and use Visual C++ 15.7 along with Visual Studio 17 version 15.7.6. Let us wait until Microsoft fix it up.

Comment: ICEs (Internal Compiler Error) are worth bug reports to Microsoft.

Comment: Either way you're going to need to produce a [MCVE].

Comment: ***Does anyone have a clue what should I do?*** Report this to Microsoft since it is a compiler bug. However don't expect a quick fix.

Comment: While you are waiting you may want to install an older version of Visual Studio: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/productinfo/installing-an-earlier-release-of-vs2017

Comment: Visual Studio 2017 15.7.6 does not have this issue.

Comment: Link to the error report for this issue: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/394989/internal-compiler-error-in-typesc-line-4563.html